# Show different image on date change in flutter

Tags: android, ios, flutter, dart

I have a scenario where I have 99 images, each day one image should be shown on a screen on date change and they should be in order. It should loop for ever. I'm trying this in flutter. Need some help.

Comment: Could you show what you have tried?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found answer by using json, I created a key value pair,where key is date and value is the url for image. I stored 
json file in application. Hope it helps others too. Writing program has many different approach. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Easiest way is to create a list with all the images you want and use the DateTime to retrieve the image like this:

```
const list = const [photo1, photo2, photo3];
```

To retrieve a photo would be:

```
//One day is 86400000 milliseconds

final daysSinceEpoch = DateTime.now().millisecondsSinceEpoch ~/ 86400000;

yourPhoto = list[daysSinceEpoch % list.length];
```

Each day that passes, the next photo in the list is retreived.

However, this is not real time, if the user is in your app at 00:00, the image will not be rebuilt unless `setstate` is called.

Moreover, take in mind that this solution calculates days from Epoch in UTC, if you want it in local time, you will need to tweak it yourself!

I hope this can help you!

Comment: It didn't work for me, now I'm planning to make a json file and fetch data as per date. Problem hereto filter as per date.

Comment: Hello Mohammed, it works, 100% sure. However, it won't start in the 1st photo. If you try it today, it will fetch the photo number 79, tomorrow it will fetch the 80, etc. Every user will get the same photo each day. If you need to start in the 1st one, you save the day that the app was installed and create a variable daysSinceInstallation. The logic is the same.